# SQL and Hibernate - repeatedly count table rows

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Suppose I have two tables, eg `thread` and `author`, where
**`thread`**

```
+------+--------+-...-+
| id   | author | ... |
+------+--------+-...-+
```

and **`author`**

```
+----+-...-+
| id | ... |
+----+-...-+
```

where `thread.author` has a foreign key on `author.id`. It's a little part of a forum project.
I'm running a Java application that use Hibernate ORM to access the database. So, I basically have 3 layers: Logic layer (Java classes) <--> Data access layer (Hibernate) <--> Database.

Now, consider this scenario: I often need to have the number of threads for a lot of user. So, basically I think I have these different solutions:

1. Leave the DB as it is and every time invoke a get on the DB (the Hibernate equivalent of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM thread WHERE author='some_id'`). It seems quite inefficient because it access the DB a lot of times.
2. Modify the `author` table adding a column like `threads_number`. However, this raise another point: which layer updates this column? A DB trigger (which seems quite unportable between different databases) or the application layer (which is good but at the same time it can lead to inconsistencies)?
3. A (materialized) view. It seems reasonable, but I think I have the same problems of point 2: which layer updates the view and check the consistence?

What is the best option?

Answer (score 0):

The second way is difficult. You have one-to-many relation, so You should store multiple threads ids in single author.threads_number field, but that is very bad practice.
Materialized view would'n help You and typical view is the same as first way - You need to select data many times from database.
All in all, You really need to achieve data many times so You need to receive that many times.
All you can do is to use hibernate to access to database. Hibernate could read stored data from cache without using database connection and can manage database connection pool to achieve best performance.

Comment: well, actually I don't want the threads ids, but only their total number.

Comment: There is no need to keep threads and thread counter simultaneously. In any way, You need to read and receive that data from database or hibernate cache. Do You really need to store threads in database? Threads could be short-living, even shorter than store operation.

Comment: Read threads as synonym of topic (it'a a forum project ;) ). Consider [this](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/89/) page for example, particularly the column `Replies`. The problem is similar to mine: do they invoke a get on DB for every single row of the page? Or do they store some additional (redundant, if you want) info for every threads?

Comment: As far as I know, most forum scripts invoke single sql query to receive every row of such view (name, replies count, last reply date, etc.) or even single query to get all rows metadata. There is no need to store redundand data and manage consistency. SQL is really eficient, especially to read, so You should't be worry about multiple "SELECT" operations.